# При интеграции с Firebase приложение крашится. Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, firebase

**Всех приветствую!**

Уже который час пытаюсь понять суть проблемы.
Делаю приложение по урокам в youtube, и на этапе интеграции FireBase получаю странную ошибку.

На данный момент даже нет никакого кода работающего с Firebase, однако сразу после интеграции приложение перестает работать, а именно крашится сразу после запуска. Отладка происходит через ADB на мобильном устройстве.

***Выходит следующий лог:***

```
2021-05-14 20:27:42.899 19977-19977/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.vpd, PID: 19977
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discoverLazy(ComponentDiscovery.java:112)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(FirebaseApp.java:418)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:299)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2154)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2128)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6765)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6615)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:232)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1953)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

**А вот так выглядит мой build.gradle**

[image: build.grade]

**А вот второй**
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/110lj.png

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в библиотеке Firebase используются лямбды, а они доступны только в Java 8. Чтобы обеспечить совместимость с такой библиотекой, необходимо добавить поддержку Java 8 в build.gradle уровня приложения в блок `android`:

```
android {

    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    
}
```